# Render a list of checkboxes from api and sending an update using hooks

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I want to use hooks for my component which renders a list of checkboxes and be able to update the status of each checkbox independently.

I am using useSelector() for retrieving the data for the checkboxes which I previously retrieved from the UI by using useDispatch()

```
function Example() {
    const [checkboxStates, setCheckboxStates] = React.useState({});

    // TODO: Implement functionality
    const handleChange = name => event => {
        setCheckboxStates({ ...checkboxStates, [name]: event.target.checked });
    };

    const userToken = useSelector(state => state.user.token);
    const locale = useSelector(state => state.translations.locale);
    const listOfElements = useSelector(
        state => state.x.listOfElements
    );

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const getListOfElements = useCallback(
        (parameters, token) =>
            dispatch(
                Actions.getListOfElements(parameters, token)
            ),
        [dispatch]
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        getListOfElements(
            { language: locale, version: new Date().getFullYear() },
            userToken
        );
    }, [getListOfElements, locale, userToken]);

    return listOfElements.map(item => (
        <FormControlLabel
            key={item.id}
            control={
                <Checkbox
                    checked={item.checked}
                    // TODO: Handle onChange
                />
            }
            label={item.name}
        />
    ));
};
```

I would expect that I can update the state of the checkboxes and send these data again back to the api but right now I don't know how to implement the onChange handler in a hooks version.

In a version without hooks, I would map the redux store to my component's props and state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working example. The key is to call the function which updates the value on the remote server directly in your *onChange()* handler.

Furthermore, you can update your own reducer to reflect also those changes directly in you redux store, without the need to request again the data from the remote server.

```
function Example() {
    const userToken = useSelector(state => state.user.token);
    const locale = useSelector(state => state.translations.locale);
    const listOfElements = useSelector(state => state.x.listOfElements);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const getListOfElements = useCallback(
        (parameters, token) =>
            dispatch(Actions.getListOfElements(parameters, token)),
        [dispatch]
    );
    const updateElementOnRemote = useCallback(
        (parameters, token) =>
            dispatch(Actions.updateElementOnRemote(parameters, token)),
        [dispatch]
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        getListOfElements(
            { language: locale, version: new Date().getFullYear() },
            userToken
        );
    }, [getListOfElements, locale, userToken]);

    const handleChange = event => {
        updateElementOnRemote(
            {
                language: locale,
                version,
                value: {
                    id: event.target.id,
                    checked: event.target.checked,
                },
            },
            userToken
        );
    };

    return listOfElements.map(item => (
        <FormControlLabel
            key={item.id}
            control={
                <Checkbox
                    id={item.id}
                    checked={item.checked}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            }
            label={item.name}
        />
    ));
}
```